# How to allow a GCP Identity to modify specific service accounts

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-iam, google-cloud-iam

I have a service account that Terraform uses to manage my cloud resources, let's call it `resource-manager-sa`. I need to give it enough access to create/delete/edit other service accounts but not to be able to change itself or other SAs in the project that it isn't supposed to touch.

I tried adding a condition there but it seems like 'service accounts' are not one of the types of resources that [you can use](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/conditions-resource-attributes) in conditions (?). Here's my HCL snippet for binding that role (the fact that I'm using Terraform is irrelevant here):

```
resource "google_project_iam_member" "service-account" {
  project = var.project
  role    = "roles/iam.serviceAccountAdmin"
  member  = "serviceAccount:${google_service_account.resource-manager-sa.email}"

  condition {
    title      = "Can manage Blah Blah SA"
    expression = "resource.name.extract('/serviceAccounts/{name}').startsWith('blah-blah@')"
  }
}
```

When I remove the condition everything works but `resource-manager-sa` has far more permissions than it needs. It can even modify itself to escalate its own privileges. After I add the condition, boom, it cannot access any service accounts:

> Error: Error when reading or editing Service Account `"projects/***/serviceAccounts/blah-blah@***.iam.gserviceaccount.com"`: googleapi: Error 403: Permission `iam.serviceAccounts.get` is required to perform this operation on service account `projects/***/serviceAccounts/blah-blah@***.iam.gserviceaccount.com`., forbidden

I feel like I'm doing something fundamentally wrong here but I cannot find a good example configuration that does what I'm trying to achieve here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Service Accounts are also a resource. As such, you can assign IAM permissions for identities at the service account level instead of at the project level. This means you can create a service account with no permissions/roles and grant that service account permissions to another service account.

Using Terraform review the [google_service_account_iam_member](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/google/latest/docs/resources/google_service_account_iam#google_service_account_iam_member) resource. This will provide you with the granularity that you asked about and not allow escalation of privilege.

Comment: Using service account as a resource is exactly what I'm trying to do here. `blah-blah@....` is the resource, `resource-manager-sa@....` should have access to that resource. Thanks!

Comment: I wanted to do something similar but instead of defining explicitly which service account Terraform could modify I wanted it to be able all (so that I don't have to add new service accounts) EXCEPT itself. Do you know how to achieve that? I also was thinking about the approach with IAM condition and google_project_iam_member  but couldn't figure out the condition

Comment: @Prusdrum - I am not sure what you are asking. Create a new question and comment with the link.

Comment: Sure, @JohnHanley, here's the link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77786599/how-to-disallow-a-gcp-service-account-from-modifying-a-specific-service-account