# How to disallow a GCP service account from modifying a specific service account in Terraform

Tags: google-cloud-platform, terraform, service-accounts, google-iam, google-cloud-iam

I have a service account that Terraform uses to manage my cloud resources (let's call it `resource-manager-sa`). I want it to be able to create/edit/delete other service accounts, but I don't want it to elevate its own permissions.

I know I could use `google_service_account_iam_member` (as I have seen [in other StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66897543/how-to-allow-a-gcp-identity-to-modify-specific-service-accounts)) to allow access to other service accounts e.g.

```
resource "google_service_account_iam_member" "admin-account-iam" {
  service_account_id = google_service_account.resource_manager_sa.name
  role               = "roles/iam.serviceAccountUser"
  member             = "serviceAccount:${google_service_account.other_sa.email}"
}
```

but that would require me to define all service accounts that I want the `resource-manager-sa` to manage. Instead I wanted to add access to all service accounts by default, but only disable access to itself (so that when I create new service accounts, I know Terraform will be able to manage them).

My initial idea was to use [IAM conditions](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/conditions-overview), something like (it's not going to work):

```
resource "google_project_iam_member" "service-account" {
  project = var.project
  role    = "roles/iam.serviceAccountAdmin"
  member  = "serviceAccount:${google_service_account.resource-manager-sa.email}"

  condition {
    title      = "Cannot manage itself"
    expression = "!resource.name.startsWith('resource-manager-sa@')"
  }
}
```

However, I couldn't find anything that suggest that this is possible in the documentation: https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/conditions-resource-attributes

Is something like this achievable, and also is something like this recommendable or would you consider it a bad practice?

Comment: You are on the right track using IAM Conditional Role Bindings. Add a tag to the service account and then write a condition that `resource.matchTagId()` any resource with that tag ID and tag value. You can deny the service account from modifying itself. https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/tags-access-control Of course, make sure that the service account does not have permission to create/modify resource tags. I would post an answer except I have not thought through any security issues or written the conditional role bindings.

Comment: Please post an answer once you have something working.

Comment: Ultimately I don't have a working solution because we dropped this task and deprioritized it. However, based on the documentation we found that:
- service account is not listed in the resource name attribute: https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/conditions-attribute-reference#resource-attributes-table:~:text=Resource%20name%20attribute
- similarly with resource tags: https://cloud.google.com/resource-manager/docs/tags/tags-supported-services#supported_service_resources
- we also found this issue for supporting IAM resources in IAM conditions: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/180035124